# Webwork action vs. servlet and other plugin admin ui questions

Tags: confluence

I'm trying to add a configuration to my plugin, but I'm rather confused about my options. Can anyone give me a comparison of webwork actions vs servlets, especially with regard to configuration UIs.

My background so far is that I've went through [this tutorial](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Plugin+tutorial+-+Writing+an+Admin+Configuration+Screen). After that I found out that all of the plugins I've installed use actions, and looking at some existing code I see that actions seem much more straightforward to implement and use (no need to implement a JavaScript/REST interface).

I'm confused as to why the tutorial seems to overcomplicate things, and actually makes no mention of a much simpler way of doing the same thing. Anyone?

On top of that, I've seen at least three different ways to save the settings: using `PluginSettingsFactory`, `BandanaManager`, or `ConfigurationManager`. More confusion! What's the "modern" way to save settings in confluence these days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Webwork Action vs. Servlet

- A Webwork Action has the advantage that you can use the built in velocity template mechanism that comes along with webwork in confluence and all the advantages of webwork itself.
- Both variants have the advantage of dependency injection via in confluence built in spring webframework.
- Using a servlet rather than the webwork action gives you independence across all atlassian plattform software because not all atlassian products use webwork.
- The plugin descriptor in the atlassian-plugin.xml allows both methods for plugin configuration page:

---

```
<atlassian-plugin key="${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}" name="${project.name}" plugins-version="2"> 
    <plugin-info>
        <description>${project.description}</description> 
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <vendor name="${project.organization.name}" url="${project.organization.url}"/>  
        <param name="plugin-icon">images/pluginIcon.png</param>  
        <param name="plugin-logo">images/pluginLogo.png</param>  
        <param name="configure.url">/admin/plugins/PATHTOYOURCONFIGPAGE</param>  
    </plugin-info>  
    ...  
</atlassian-plugin>
```

### Storing plugin settings

If you have a look at the [PluginSettingsFactory interface](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/javadoc/sal/2.0/reference/com/atlassian/sal/api/pluginsettings/PluginSettingsFactory.html) and the list of all known classes that implements this interface, you will find the ConfluencePluginSettingsFactory. There's a `public void setBandanaManager (BandanaManager bandanaManager)` method declared. This is a dependency injection for the BandanaManager. This indicates that the Implementation of the [PluginSettingsFactory interface](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/javadoc/sal/2.0/reference/com/atlassian/sal/api/pluginsettings/PluginSettingsFactory.html) uses the BandanaManager for property persistence.

I personally don't know that *ConfigurationManager* thing. I use BandanaManager for all my confluence plugins to store properties that would be set via admin settings page or somewhere else.

Have a look here for the state of the art way to persist data as described by atlassian: [Persistence in Confluence](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Persistence+in+Confluence). They use the BandanaManager also.